# Windows Service: Service missing from list of startup objects

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've built a service and of course I changed the names of some of the objects (including the service itself) to more closely align to the name of the project itself.

I must have screwed up the name change because when I attempted to build it threw an error about the startup object.  It forced me to switch the startup object to `"Sub Main"` instead of the `Service Object`.

The `Service Object` itself is no longer listed in the startup objects in My Project, and the service itself won't work because, of course, there IS NO Sub Main.  What do I need to do to get the service back to being the startup object?

Answer (score 0):

In the VB.NET project, ensure the application type is Windows Service and the startup object is the class name of the service.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me, but after I exited VS and came back in, the option for the service object appeared.